# How to set and/or retrieve default cell padding in iText 7

Tags: itext7

When you create a table in iText 7 using the Table and Cell classes, the table cells come with some padding built in by default. As far as I can tell by looking at a generated document, it appears to be about 2 PDF units.

Is there any way I can retrieve this value for use in calculations? Also, is there any way I can change this default, so that I can set my own padding to be used in all cells in all tables, instead of having to set it individually on every cell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please take a look at the [iText 7: Building Blocks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks) tutorial.

In the [Before we start](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/we-start-overview-classes-and-interfaces) section, we see that every building block is derived from a class named `ElementPropertyContainer`. This class is a container of properties.

In the case of the `Cell` class, there is a set of properties that define the padding. You can get these properties the generic way (using a method of the `AbstractElement` class) like this:

```
System.out.println(cell.getProperty(Property.PADDING_LEFT));
System.out.println(cell.getProperty(Property.PADDING_RIGHT));
System.out.println(cell.getProperty(Property.PADDING_TOP));
System.out.println(cell.getProperty(Property.PADDING_BOTTOM));
```

But why make it difficult if you can also simply use convenience methods that is available in the `BlockElement` class:

```
System.out.println(cell.getPaddingLeft());
System.out.println(cell.getPaddingRight());
System.out.println(cell.getPaddingTop());
System.out.println(cell.getPaddingBottom());
```

As you can see in the tutorial, the `Cell` class is a subclass of the `BlockElement` class. The `BlockElement` is a subclass of the `AbstractElement` class. The `AbstractElement` class is a subclass of the `ElementPropertyContainer` class.

If you want to change the padding (or the margin if you are so inclined), please read [chapter 5](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-5-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-2) of that tutorial. It has an example, named [CellMarginPadding](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/examples/chapter-5#2035-c05e05_cellmarginpadding.java):

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    Table table = new Table(new float[]{2, 1, 1});
    table.setBackgroundColor(Color.ORANGE);
    table.setWidthPercent(80);
    table.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    table.addCell(
        new Cell(1, 3).add("Cell with colspan 3")
            .setPadding(10).setMargin(5).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN));
    table.addCell(new Cell(2, 1).add("Cell with rowspan 2")
        .setMarginTop(5).setMarginBottom(5).setPaddingLeft(30)
        .setFontColor(Color.WHITE).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE));
    table.addCell(new Cell().add("row 1; cell 1")
        .setFontColor(Color.WHITE).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED));
    table.addCell(new Cell().add("row 1; cell 2"));
    table.addCell(new Cell().add("row 2; cell 1").setMargin(10)
        .setFontColor(Color.WHITE).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED));
    table.addCell(new Cell().add("row 2; cell 2").setPadding(10)
        .setFontColor(Color.WHITE).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED));
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I'm sorry if it hurts the eyes a bit, but using those colors seemed like the best way to explain the difference between the margin and the padding to me.

Most of the properties are inherited. For instance: if you set the font for a `Div`, that font will be the default font for all the elements added to that `Div`. There are some exceptions though. The padding is one of them. This is how the default values for the properties specific to the `Cell` class were defined:

```
@Override
public <T1> T1 getDefaultProperty(int property) {
    switch (property) {
        case Property.BORDER:
            return (T1) (Object) DEFAULT_BORDER;
        case Property.PADDING_BOTTOM:
        case Property.PADDING_LEFT:
        case Property.PADDING_RIGHT:
        case Property.PADDING_TOP:
            return (T1) (Object) 2f;
        default:
            return super.<T1>getDefaultProperty(property);
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is no padding value for the complete cell; the padding consists of four values that incidentally are identical by default.

If you don't like to define a padding different from the default for each `Cell`, just create a subclass of `Cell` and call it `MyCustomCell`. Make it custom in the sense that it uses the padding of your choice by overriding the `getDefaultProperty()` class.

In the tutorial, you'll find an example of a subclass that draws cells with borders that have rounded corners so that we don't have to set declare a renderer every time we want to introduce rounder corners.

I am the original author of that documentation. I hope you find it useful to answer these and other questions about the `Cell` and other objects in iText 7.

Comment: Sorry Bruno, but this doesn't answer my question. I specifically asked for a way to set the default cell padding _without_ having to set it individually on every cell. I also asked for a way to retrieve the default, but getPaddingLeft() (or whatever) doesn't return this - instead it returns null if I haven't set it myself, even though the generated PDF clearly shows that the default padding is something similar to 2 units. If I explicitly set it to 0, then this implicit padding disappears.

Comment: I've just seen your edit, which does attempt to answer the second part of my question, although I am a little disappointed that I have to subclass Cell in order to do this, and that there appears to be no way to access or alter the implicit default?

Comment: And I gave the example of the subclass of `Cell` that avoids having to set the renderer for every cell. You also don't seem to understand that there is no default padding *for the box*. The padding consists of four values that can be identical (which is what you assume), but don't have to be identical.

Comment: You say there is no default padding, but if that is the case can you please explain where the padding comes from around the cell, which I can clearly see in my generated document, and which disappears when I explicitly set the padding to zero?

Comment: Once again, you didn't read what I said. I said: there is no default padding **for the box**. There are four different defaults: one for each side of the box. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ah - so it's hard-coded in the getDefaultProperty() method, so I can't access it and I can't override it for all cells (only for my own custom Cell sub-classes)?

Comment: The only other option to define a default is using a `static` member-variable, but that's dangerous, isn't it? When you change it in one place, it changes everywhere. That can cause undesired side-effects.

Comment: Knowing how much easier iText 7 is to use when compared to iText 5, I don't understand why you'd make such a problem out of this.

Comment: "When you change it in one place, it changes everywhere" - well, that is generally the point of a default, however you implement it! iText 7 has many good features and I'm not comparing it to iText 5 or anything else. I just think it's a bit of a nuisance that it's  setting parameters in my layout for me that I have no access to or control over, except by sub-classing the framework.

Comment: Your last edit has answered one of my questions though - I can access this value using (e.g.) getDefaultProperty(Property.PADDING_LEFT), which means that I can now use this value in my calculations - so thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

I did this in C# per @Bruno Lowagie override route to set a default as no padding and no border:

```
public class BorderlessCell : Cell
    {
        public BorderlessCell(int rowSpan, int colSpan) : base(rowSpan, colSpan) { }
        public BorderlessCell() : base() { }
        public override T1 GetDefaultProperty<T1>(int property) 
        {
            switch (property) 
            {
                case Property.BORDER:
                    return (T1)(Object)(Border.NO_BORDER);
                case Property.PADDING_BOTTOM:
                case Property.PADDING_LEFT:
                case Property.PADDING_RIGHT:
                case Property.PADDING_TOP:
                   return (T1)(Object)(0);
                default:
                    return base.GetDefaultProperty<T1>(property);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What works for me was editing the WidthPercentage, for example:

```
table.setWidthPercentage(100)
```